# How do I register single event listener for all buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

How can I listen to all button clicks in my WPF app. Maybe include some of the checkboxes or so but ideally I do not want to have extra event handler.

I want to collect initial statistics to know how people use our application. I want to make sure I do not interfere with any other event handling functionality.

In application new windows are being opened and closed with their own buttons so I can not do it statically.

Alternatively is there any common way to collect usage statistics from WPF apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I listen to all button clicks in my WPF app?

You can hook events to all objects for a type by using the [EventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventmanager%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Button), Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Button_Click));

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

> In application new windows are being opened and closed with their own
>   buttons so I can not do it statically.

If you create these Windows in WPF, you can hook into the [Window events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window_events.aspx) such as Closed, Sizechanged and Got/LostFocus(). If these Windows are not WPF/Winform based you can use a [ShellHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This worked for me nicely plus it has least distraction to my code. It is also handling other types of buttons which is good side effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a style:

.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Button_Click" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button x:Name="b1" Click="Button1_Click" Content="1" />
        <Button x:Name="b2" Click="Button2_Click" Content="2" />
        <Button Content="other" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("some button");
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("button1");
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("button2");
    }
}
```

The style can be application wide when put into app.xaml.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Commands for button click event handling. Every window will have the CommandBinding instances where in their Execute handling methods you can send info about usage of current button into some static singleton instance of some class which will hold the results for you. Commands and CommandBindings are not necessary, but if you are using the MVVM pattern, then try to use them. And instead of static singleton use custom Service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Window_Loaded event of each window, and iterate over your VisualTree, find all Buttons and register your additional Generic handler:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Capture all buttons of this form.
        findButtons(this);
    }

    public void findButtons(FrameworkElement parent)
    {
        int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

        for(int i=0; i<childCount; i++){
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent,i);

            if (child is Button){
                  ((Button)child).Click += All_Button_Click;
            }

            var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
            findButtons(frameworkElement);
        }
    }

    private void All_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Generic Handler");
    }
```

All your buttons can remain as they are, and have their own custom event handler.
You can also use a handler on your mainwindow to cover all forms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had an idea to do it I dont know if it would be perfect or not.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    //Create list of string in your App class this will contain the names of button in order they are clicked
    public static List<string> ButtonNames = new List<string>();
}
```

Create a custom Button class that inherits Button class and use this CustomButton class instead of Button in your application and overload button class's OnClick method and Subscribe an event in it . this will add Button name to the above created ButtonNames List

```
 public class MyButton : Button
{
    private bool isClickEventAttached = false;
    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        if (!isClickEventAttached)
        {
            this.Click += MyButton_Click;
            isClickEventAttached = true;
        }
        //dont forget to do this base.Click() otherwise your 
        //button click event that you will subscribe in your application will not fire
        base.OnClick();
    }

    private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button=sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
            App.ButtonNames.Add((button.Name));
    }
}
```

**xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:commonControls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <commonControls:MyButton x:Name="mybutton1" Click="MyButton_Click_1"/>
    <commonControls:MyButton x:Name="mybutton2" Click="MyButton_Click_2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    private void MyButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void MyButton_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I hope you will get an idea what I am trying to say